# Unresolved compilation at ch14Eamples.MultipleStageDemo.main(MultipleStageDemo.java:24)

Tags: java, javafx

I was using Eclipse EE but it would display an error when I tried importing javafx.application.Application so I switched to Eclipse SDK version. 
Now there is no error on the import but I can't get it compiled.

I'm following a recent tutorial straight out of my Java book so I don't know why the error is occurring.

Here is my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MultipleStageDemo extends Application{

    @Override //Override the start method in the application class

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    //Create a scene and place a button in the scene
            Scene scene = new Scene(new Button("OK"), 200, 250);
            primaryStage.setTitle("MyJavaFx"); //set the stage title
            primaryStage.setScene(scene); //Place the scene in the stage
            primaryStage.show(); //display the stage


            Stage stage = new Stage(); //create 2nd stage
            stage.setTitle("Second Stage"); 
            stage.setScene(new Scene(new Button("New Stage"), 100, 100));
            stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
            Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

Here are my errors:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    at ch14Eamples.MultipleStageDemo.main(MultipleStageDemo.java:24)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application ch14Eamples.MultipleStageDemo
```

Comment: That link doesn't address this issue one bit.

Answer (score 1):

The output at runtime indicates that the real problem is your code did not compile.  In Eclipse you'll see various red indicators of the problems and it will pop up a confirmation dialog when you try to run warning you that the project did not compile.

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>    at ch14Eamples.MultipleStageDemo.main(MultipleStageDemo.java:24)
> ```

In the method `main()`, on line 24 of your MultipleStageDemo.java file is where you'll find the compilation error.  Look in the Problems view in Eclipse for the complete compilation error message.  My guess is it can't find the class `Application`, and you probably have unresolved import errors too.  This means the classpath of your project is incomplete since it is missing the library/libraries you require.  Since I have not worked with javafx, I don't know what the libraries are or where to find them.